# Yii2 get value before save in model

Tags: yii2, before-save

I would like create special validation in my model and I need get transaction_id but it return null. It's normlan becouse model is not save, but is there some trick which will allow me get this transaction_id before save?

I read  about `Blameable Behavior`, but it save value after validation

Model:

```
<?php

class CommentForm extends ActiveRecord
{
    public $type;
    public $content;

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['type'], 'required'],
            [['content'], 'string', 'length' => [1, 140]],
            [['content'], 'required',],
            [['type'], 'in', 'range' => Message::getCommentTypes()],
            [['transaction_id'], 'canSendComment', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'skipOnError' => false],
        ];
    }

    public function canSendComment($attribute)
    {
        $message = Message::find()
            ->where([
                'transaction_id' => $this->transaction_id,
                'sender_id' => $this->sender_id,
                'type' => Message::getCommentTypes(),
            ])
            ->one();
    }
}
```

contoller action

```
public function actionShow($id)
    {

$transaction = Transaction::find()        
            ->where(['id' => $id])
            ->one();        


$comment = new CommentForm();

        if ($comment->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $comment->validate()) {

            $comment->transaction_id = $id;
            $comment->sender_id = Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
            $comment->save();

            Yii::$app->getSession()
                ->addFlash('success', '<strong>success</strong> OK!!.');

            return $this->redirect(['transaction/show', 'id' => $id]);
        }


        return $this->render($view, [  
    'transaction' => $transaction,
            'comment' => $comment,
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: `transaction_id` is autoincrement or you set this manually in model?

Comment: manually in model

Comment: So u have access to this attribute, no matter its saved or not. Problem here is with `sender_id`, you dont have any rule to this attribute, so propably youre not setting it. Try add `var_dump($this->transaction_id, $this->sender_id);die;` before `$message` variable in `canSendComment()` function and analyze results.

Comment: this is results `NULL NULL`

Comment: My bad, add this rule:
`[['transaction_id','sender_id'], 'integer'],` before your validator and try var_dump again :)

Comment: Still `NULL NULL` :/  in contoller I have `$model->transaction_id = $id;` it will be good idea to set `$model->transaction_id` before `$model->load()` ?

Comment: Are you sure `$id` is not empty?

Comment: yea I am sure because it is a parameter of function and the same function render my view and it works

Comment: Please share full model and controller code.

Comment: I updated the question, full controller is too big to share it

Comment: You set `transaction_id` and `sender_id` after `$comment->validate()`, so it always will be null.